# Storing binary values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a BQ table with binary data. One way is to create it with the BOOL specification. However, I want to be able to directly do arithmetic operations on its columns which is not possible with BOOL.

What is the best way to create this table with the minimum storage requirement?

For example, I create the table below and all columns are implicitly defined as Integers

```
create or replace table temp1
as
select 1 as a, 0 as b, 1 as c;
```

Is there a way to reduce table size?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing images as binary i do recommend GCS. Suppose that  you are not storing images, You can store binary data in BigQuery  as a string.
for your operations you can use some predefined functions as :

`select  bqutil.fn.from_binary('111000001')`

[image]

Or you can use other functions like: `SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING()`...etc